# Where is the `\marginpar` command defined?

Tags: marginpar, documentation

I couldn't find official documentation for the `\marginpar` command. Where is it defined?

I looked at the documentation for [Standard Document Classes for LaTeX Version 2e](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/classes.pdf). While this discusses `\marginparpush`, `\marginparsep` and `\marginparwidth` I couldn't find the normal `\marginpar` command.

I also tried `texdoc marginpar` in my terminal, but this opens the documentation for the [minipage-marginpar](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minipage-marginpar) package.

Comment: It is a LaTeX kernel command. You should find documentation in every complete LaTeX introduction (usually not in short introductions). And also [at wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Footnotes_and_Margin_Notes#Margin_Notes). And because it is a kernel command, you can find it in source2e.pdf (but IMHO this is not really intended for users).

Comment: it is define in the format, in latex.ltx. The source code is in ltfloat.dtx

Comment: If the true issue ins not where it is defined but *how* is defined you can use  `\meaning\marginpar` in a  document or just `pdflatex "\show\marginpar"`.